# "useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component." . Como utilizar esse Router?

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Eu tenho um formulário de login e logo após dar o submit ele deve ir para a página Home. Estou usando React js e para navegar entre as paginas estou usando o "useNavigate" do "react-router-dom". Implementei uma função de click do botão e coloquei para navegar para a home ali, depois inseri essa função no onClick do botão. Quando fiz isso o formulário sumiu e surgiu esse erro no console:

> "useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a Router component."

Não entendi onde devo colocar esse componente Router dentro do meu formulário, alguem pode explicar por favor?

segue meu código:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from "yup";
import styles from '../styles/Login.css'

const schema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().required("* o nome é obrigatório"),
    email: yup.string().email("Digite um email válido").required("* o email é obrigatório"),    
  }).required();


export default function Login(){

    const history = useNavigate();

    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)
      });

    function onSubmit(userData){
        console.log(userData)        
    }  
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        history('/');
    }

    return(
        <div className='box'>
            <div className='login-section'></div>
                <div className='login-text'>Por favor, insira o seu Nome e Email</div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <label>
                        Nome
                        <input type='text' {...register("name", { required: true })}/>
                        <span>{errors.name?.message}</span>
                        
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input type='text' {...register("email" , { required: true })}/>
                        <span>{errors.email?.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    <button type='submit' onClick={handleClick}>Iniciar</button>
                </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O que provavelmente está ocorrendo é que seu componente Login não está dentro de um router. Para que o `useNavigate` funcione é necessário que esse elemento já esteja vinculado a uma rota ou ao menos esteja dedntro do componente `BrowserRouter`, caso contrario o mesmo não vai funcionar.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

No exemplo acima o seu problema já será resolvido